# Access Remote Computer for Mostly Blind Person

Tags: windows

I am supporting a friend out of town that cannot see very well.  We have installed Team Viewer on his computer, but he cannot see the password well enough to connect.

Can we setup some type of easy access so I can get in whenever he starts Team Viewer on his end without using a password?

Comment: Can they use Magnifier built into Windows to see better?

Answer (score 13):

TeamViewer allows you to set a fixed password, precisely for these sorts of situations.

In your friend's TeamViewer settings:

1. Enter a strong password that you don't use anywhere else
2. Choose random password: "Disabled (no random password)"

[image]

TeamViewer always needs a password for security reasons but the password doesn't need to *change* every time you connect.

You can also add his computer using the "Add remote computer" option in your TeamViewer settings, so that your TeamViewer remembers both your friend's TeamViewer ID (which won't change unless he gets a new computer) as well as his TeamViewer password (which is now fixed):

[image]

[image]

You will soon be able to instantly connect to your friend's PC simply by double clicking on an icon in your TeamViewer, without typing anything!

[image]

Comment: Also note that TeamViewer can be configured to start when the computer starts, increasing the convenience.

Comment: Yeah. That's actually the default behavior when you install it. It's probably already doing that but they haven't noticed! Windows hides TeamViewer in the Taskbar notification area unless you explicitly tell it not to. Most users don't even realize it's running at startup because of this.